# Meteor: Convert MongoDB server code for client side

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, meteor

I can fetch data from meteor mongo terminal using this code but can't fetch data from the client. I know for the client site need different syntax but I am new on this environment. How can I call from a client site? Thanks

```
db.events.aggregate([
    { "$project": { 
         "year": { "$year": "$date" }, 
         "month": { "$month": "$date" },
         "day": { "$dayOfMonth": "$date" }

    }},
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": null, 
        "distinctDate": { "$addToSet": { "year": "$year", "month": "$month", "day": "$day" }}
    }}
])
```

Comment: It is a very Meteor specific case of having Minimongo as a client side wrapper for Mongo-Collections. Unfortunately it's documentation is not sufficient enough to reveal whether a certain feature is  present there or not. OP expects the above described command to work (since even complex queries do work) but it does not. I don't see an issue with this question.

Answer (score 2):

Currently Minimongo does not support aggregation.

But you can give a shot to [meteorhacks:aggregate](https://github.com/meteorhacks/meteor-aggregate)

**Edit**

Usage example:

> meteor add meteorhacks:aggregate Then simply use .aggregate function
>   like below.

```
var metrics = new Mongo.Collection('metrics');
var pipeline = [
  {$group: {_id: null, resTime: {$sum: "$resTime"}}}
];
var result = metrics.aggregate(pipeline);
```

Comment: @Fawzi Could you convert my code on this package environment? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: not that hard, same as your code, but instead of `db.events.aggregate` use  
 `Events.aggregate([
    { "$project": { 
         "year": { "$year": "$date" }, ....)`